# Active Directory username policy and Exchange server

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, policy

I am working in an organization that uses Active Directory and Exchange Server.. and
I want to apply a policy to Active Directory and this policy is related to the method of naming the username so that the first letter is from the name of the employee and the first letter of the father’s name followed by the family name. In addition to its name in Exchange Server, Its possible to generate names according to username policy to the active directory and exchange server? And how can applying?
#Active_Directory #Exchange_Server
#policy

I am try to create policy email address in exchange but it doesn’t work with Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

You may standardize user account names (SamAccountName) New-ADUser with "instance" parameter.

Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/blob/main/docset/winserver2012-ps/activedirectory/New-ADUser.md

You may also use Active Directory Users and Computers to prepare templates for the new users.

Pls note that these are templates, does not dictate any policy / enforcement.

If you create security principals through Exchange Server, you may set the SamAccountName parameter to a value extracted from Name, Family Name etc during execution of new-mailbox cmdlet.

The email address policy in Exchange Server dictates/enforces naming standard for only the email addresses of the users / groups. It does not dictate any policy on other AD attributes.

Finally if you would like to import from a list of users in a csv file to create new AD users, then you may check and set SamAccountName attribute beforehand for the convenience of your standards, then you may bulk create users using import-csv powershell cmdlet.